# ObjectDisposedException in asyncrhonous client-server socket error

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client

I'm writing an asynchronous client/server socket following the MSDN code. It is supposed to work like this: the client sends 10 operations to the server and the server reads them, validates that it can retrieve the money from the account, perfoms the operation if it's valid and sends it back to the client.

The server recieves the operations just fine but when it sends them back the client throws ObjectDisposedException. Does the server socket close before the client reads the operation? Do I have to wait for the client to read before closing the socket?

Client code:

```
public class StateObject
{
    //Socket del cliente
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    //Puerto para el servidor
    //
    private const int puerto = 11000;

    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    //Respuesta del servidor
    private static String response = String.Empty;
    private static Operacion recibido;

    private static void StartClient(Operacion op)
    {  
        try
        {
            //Establecemos un endpoint 
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, puerto);

            //Creamos el socket del cliente  
            Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            //Nos conectamos al endpoint del servidor  
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            //Enviamos los datos al servidor  
            Send(client, op);
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            //Recibimos respuesta del servidor  
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();
            if(recibido.Valido.Equals("false"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No se ha podido proceder con una operación: {0} {1} {2}",
                    recibido.Origen, recibido.Destino, recibido.Cantidad);
            }

            //Liberamos el socket
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
        }

    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndConnect(ar);
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            //Hacemos casting del StateObject y recuperamos el Socket
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            //Leemos los datos del servidor  
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                //Puede que no hayamos leído todo así que se va añadiendo  
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                //Se recupera lo que falta  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    //Deserializacion del objeto
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                    recibido = (Operacion)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Operacion)).Deserialize(stream);

                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.  
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, Operacion data)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Operacion));
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
        byte[] byteData = ((MemoryStream)stream).ToArray();
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Operaciones enviadas al servidor. {0} bytes enviados.", bytesSent);
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Operacion op = new Operacion("Destino1", "Destino2", 15, "");
            StartClient(op);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Fin de envío.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    // Thread signal.  
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static List<Operacion> opList;
    private static Dictionary<string, double> listaCuentas;
    private static String respuesta = String.Empty;

    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {
    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {

                allDone.Reset();

                //Empezamos a escuchar alguna conexión 
                Console.WriteLine("Esperando conexión...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                //Esperamos a que la conexión se realice antes de continuar 
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(opList.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        allDone.Set();

        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String cuenta1 = String.Empty;
        String cuenta2 = String.Empty;
        Double cantidad = 0;
        String validez = String.Empty;

        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(state.buffer);
            Operacion recibido = (Operacion)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Operacion)).Deserialize(stream);
            cuenta1 = recibido.Origen;
            cuenta2 = recibido.Destino;
            cantidad = recibido.Cantidad;

            //Hay que incluir un lock
            Console.WriteLine("{0} envía a {1}: {2}", cuenta1, cuenta2, cantidad);
            if (cantidad <= listaCuentas[cuenta1])
            {
                lock(((ICollection)listaCuentas).SyncRoot)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fondos disponibles. Se procede a realizar la operacion.");
                    recibido.Valido = "true";
                    listaCuentas[cuenta1] = listaCuentas[cuenta1] - cantidad;
                    listaCuentas[cuenta2] = listaCuentas[cuenta2] + cantidad;
                    opList.Add(recibido);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", cuenta1, listaCuentas[cuenta1]);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", cuenta2, listaCuentas[cuenta2]);
                    Send(handler, recibido);
                }
            } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No hay fondos para realizar la operacion.");
                    recibido.Valido = "false";
                    Send(handler, recibido);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, Operacion data)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Operacion));
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
        byte[] byteData = ((MemoryStream)stream).ToArray(); 
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        { 
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesEnviados = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("[0] bytes enviados al cliente.", bytesEnviados);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }


    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        listaCuentas = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        listaCuentas.Add("Destino1", 1500 );
        listaCuentas.Add("Destino2", 2500);
        listaCuentas.Add("Destino3", 150);
        listaCuentas.Add("Destino4", 10);
        opList = new List<Operacion>();
        StartListening();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you closing the client in the method StartClient?  Your main() has a for loop to send 10 items.  Your error is due to the connection closing before all 10 items are sent.  StartClient should only make the initial connection.  There are 7 Network Layers.  The TCP connection is the Transport Layer.  You application layer is sending the 10 messages and processing the response.  The MSDN example really mixes the TCP layer and Application Layer together.  You need to separate the two layers.

Comment: So I should call StarClient() once and loop the Send method 10 times. As I understand I’m starting the client ten times and one of them closes it before the rest is sent.

Comment: You only have to start client once, not 10 times.  And you do not need to close the connection in the start method!!!

Comment: I've changed the code and I don't get that error anymore, but when the server sends the operation back the client doesn't enter ReceiveCallback when calling to BeginReceive.

Comment: When the client connects you get to ConnectCallback once which then registers the event ReceiveCallback (using BeginReceive).  When a message is received by the socket a call is made to ReceiveCallback.  Then ReceiveCallback clears the event using EndReceive registers the event,  Then a new Event is regeistered by using BeginReceive.   There is not reason you code will not get the ReceiveCallback as long as the connection still exists.  So using cmd.exe you can use >Netstat -a to see the status of all TCP connecctions to see if it closed.

Comment: Two other things I would do 1) You can use menu Debug : BreakAll to see where the code is running.  You may be blocked by one of the ManualReset 2) You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture the TCP messages.  Look for a [FIN] which is an indication the connection closed.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because your server closes the connection before the client has acknowledged the receipt of the data at the TCP layer.

When bytes are still in flight, that is they have not been ack'd by the recipient, then when you close the socket, the socket will send a `TCP RESET`.  If all bytes are ACK'd, then when you close the socket, the server will go through a clean `TCP_FIN` socket close down process.

This anomaly happens with small packets and `TCP DELAYED ACK` - the client, receives the bytes, it hangs on to them looking for more (delaying it's ack), the server closes the connection, but because it has not had all it's bytes ACKd it sends a RST.  The TCP Stack, which was hanging onto those bytes waiting for more and thus had not ACK'd them, does not make them available to the `socket`.  The TCP Stack will only make ACKd bytes available to the `socket`

TLDR; for a fast network you need to wait 250ms on the server side before closing the connection, if this is not a high performance app, then I suggest waiting 800ms

> As specified in RFC 1122, TCP uses delayed acknowledgments to reduce
>   the number of packets that are sent on the media. Instead of sending
>   an acknowledgment for each TCP segment received, TCP in Windows 2000
>   and later takes a common approach to implementing delayed
>   acknowledgments. As data is received by TCP on a particular
>   connection, it sends an acknowledgment back only if one of the
>   following conditions is true: No acknowledgment was sent for the
>   previous segment received. A segment is received, but no other segment
>   arrives within 200 milliseconds for that connection.